# YouTube API - Trying to fetch channel members

Tags: python, google-api, youtube-data-api, google-api-python-client

I'm currently trying to write a Python script to fetch my YouTube channel members using the YouTube API. I have created an OAuth Client and have gone through the necessary steps to setup all of my tokens (I think). This OAuth Client works when I use it to fetch a list of my channel's subscriptions and other information, but when I try to fetch my members I am receiving a 403 error. I believe this is because the [Members Documention](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/members/list) states that I have to fill out a specific [form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1ZdaHwMaIjZWtN28_NGckkbk_-Ca3vEOINbV_qBW-m_s/edit?ts=5e7bbb23&gxids=7628) to gain access to this API route. I filled out the form with all of the information I believe Google needs. But I haven't received any updates on the status of this approval or any indication if I filled this form out with the proper information.

Does anyone have any experience with using the YouTube API to fetch channel members and if I'm doing this correctly so far? And if I am doing this correctly, how long does it take for an app to be approved for access to the members API route?

For the code, I'm simply using the [Python Web Client Quickstart Guide](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/python/quickstart_web.py). I have also tried playing with the scopes with no success...

```
import os
import flask
import requests

import google.oauth2.credentials
import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
import googleapiclient.discovery

CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE = "client_secret.json"

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly']
API_SERVICE_NAME = 'youtube'
API_VERSION = 'v3'

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = '5f24ef3cf326d03'


@app.route('/')
def index():
  return print_index_table()


@app.route('/test')
def test_api_request():
  if 'credentials' not in flask.session:
    return flask.redirect('authorize')

  credentials = google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials(
      **flask.session['credentials'])

  youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
      API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials=credentials)

  # THIS WORKS
  # subs = youtube.subscriptions().list(
  #     part="snippet,contentDetails",
  #     mine=True
  # ).execute()

  # THIS DOESNT WORK
  subs = youtube.members().list(
      part="snippet",
      maxResults=50
  ).execute()

  flask.session['credentials'] = credentials_to_dict(credentials)

  return flask.jsonify(**subs)


@app.route('/authorize')
def authorize():
  flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
      CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

  flow.redirect_uri = flask.url_for('oauth2callback', _external=True)

  authorization_url, state = flow.authorization_url(
      access_type='offline',
      include_granted_scopes='true')

  flask.session['state'] = state

  return flask.redirect(authorization_url)


@app.route('/oauth2callback')
def oauth2callback():
  state = flask.session['state']

  flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
      CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, scopes=SCOPES, state=state)
  flow.redirect_uri = flask.url_for('oauth2callback', _external=True)

  authorization_response = flask.request.url
  flow.fetch_token(authorization_response=authorization_response)

  credentials = flow.credentials
  flask.session['credentials'] = credentials_to_dict(credentials)

  return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('test_api_request'))


@app.route('/revoke')
def revoke():
  if 'credentials' not in flask.session:
    return ('You need to <a href="/authorize">authorize</a> before ' +
            'testing the code to revoke credentials.')

  credentials = google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials(
      **flask.session['credentials'])

  revoke = requests.post('https://oauth2.googleapis.com/revoke',
                         params={'token': credentials.token},
                         headers={'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})

  status_code = getattr(revoke, 'status_code')
  if status_code == 200:
    return('Credentials successfully revoked.' + print_index_table())
  else:
    return('An error occurred.' + print_index_table())


@app.route('/clear')
def clear_credentials():
  if 'credentials' in flask.session:
    del flask.session['credentials']
  return ('Credentials have been cleared.<br><br>' +
          print_index_table())


def credentials_to_dict(credentials):
  return {'token': credentials.token,
          'refresh_token': credentials.refresh_token,
          'token_uri': credentials.token_uri,
          'client_id': credentials.client_id,
          'client_secret': credentials.client_secret,
          'scopes': credentials.scopes}


def print_index_table():
  return ('<table>' +
          '<tr><td><a href="/test">Test an API request</a></td>' +
          '<td>Submit an API request and see a formatted JSON response. ' +
          '    Go through the authorization flow if there are no stored ' +
          '    credentials for the user.</td></tr>' +
          '<tr><td><a href="/authorize">Test the auth flow directly</a></td>' +
          '<td>Go directly to the authorization flow. If there are stored ' +
          '    credentials, you still might not be prompted to reauthorize ' +
          '    the application.</td></tr>' +
          '<tr><td><a href="/revoke">Revoke current credentials</a></td>' +
          '<td>Revoke the access token associated with the current user ' +
          '    session. After revoking credentials, if you go to the test ' +
          '    page, you should see an <code>invalid_grant</code> error.' +
          '</td></tr>' +
          '<tr><td><a href="/clear">Clear Flask session credentials</a></td>' +
          '<td>Clear the access token currently stored in the user session. ' +
          '    After clearing the token, if you <a href="/test">test the ' +
          '    API request</a> again, you should go back to the auth flow.' +
          '</td></tr></table>')


if __name__ == '__main__':
  # When running locally, disable OAuthlib's HTTPs verification.
  # ACTION ITEM for developers:
  #     When running in production *do not* leave this option enabled.
  os.environ['OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT'] = '1'

  app.run('localhost', 8080, debug=True)
```

Specifically, these are the sections that currently work (Channels I'm subbed to) and don't work (My channel members)...

```
  # THIS WORKS
  # subs = youtube.subscriptions().list(
  #     part="snippet,contentDetails",
  #     mine=True
  # ).execute()

  # THIS DOESNT WORK
  subs = youtube.members().list(
      part="snippet",
      maxResults=50
  ).execute()
```

Comment: please edit your question and include your code.

Comment: I've edited the question so that I've included my code. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pypyodbc    
connection = pypyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};Server=ipserver;Database=DBContext;uid=yourid;pwd=passwd')   
import datetime
sql_select_Query = "  select  URLChannel,idstr from [dbo].[Channel] group by [IDStr], [URLChannel]"
cursors2 = connection.cursor()
cursors2.execute(sql_select_Query)
# get all records
records = cursors2.fetchall()
for row in records:
    youtube = build('youtube', 'v3',
                developerKey='yourdeveloperkey')
 
    ch_request = youtube.channels().list(
        part='statistics,snippet',
        id=row[1])
 
    print("url:   ", row[0]) 
    # Channel Information
    ch_response = ch_request.execute()
    urlchannel = row[0]
    idStr = row[1]
    sub = 0
    checkcondition = ch_response['items'][0]['statistics']['hiddenSubscriberCount']
    if checkcondition == False:
        sub = ch_response['items'][0]['statistics']['subscriberCount']
    vid = ch_response['items'][0]['statistics']['videoCount']
    views = ch_response['items'][0]['statistics']['viewCount']
    snippet = ch_response["items"][0]["snippet"]
    statistics = ch_response["items"][0]["statistics"]
    #channel_country = snippet["country"]
    channel_country = ''
    channel_description = snippet["description"]
    channel_creation_date = snippet["publishedAt"]
    channel_title = snippet["title"]
    cursor = connection.cursor()    
    SQLCommand = ("INSERT INTO [dbo].[Channel]([Channel_title],[Channel_country],[Channel_creation_date],[Channel_description],[subscriberCount],[videoCount],[viewCount],[URLChannel],[IDStr],[UpdateTime],[CreateTime],[UpdateUser],[CreateUser]) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)")    
    Values = [channel_title, channel_country, channel_creation_date, channel_description, sub,vid,views,urlchannel,idStr,datetime.datetime.now(),datetime.datetime.now(),"usercreate","userupdate"]   
    #Processing Query    
    cursor.execute(SQLCommand,Values)     
    #Commiting any pending transaction to the database.    
    connection.commit()    
    #closing connection    
    print("Data Successfully Inserted")
```